# How do I enter code between two list items?

Tags: bug, markdown

Look below. The code block does not get recognized between a list.

- The first item.
- The second item. bla bla bla:

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
  csrf_token = soup.select_one('meta.x_csrf')['value']
- Third item. No luck!

But it works fine after a normal paragraph:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
csrf_token = soup.select_one('meta.x_csrf')['value']
```

Well, is it not a bug in the Markdown formatting?

Comment: Just indent with 5 spaces more or use rulers to separate.

Comment: rulers? you mean pipe? this one: `|` ?

Comment: No, I meant `--------------------------------`

Comment: oh. I got it. I had to add extra four spaces indent to get the code block recognized!

Comment: Don't you mean the code belongs to the second item? That is, the intent is to have one list, not two lists?

Comment: @Sonic I know, THX.